# Use argparse with Setuptools entry_points

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools, argparse

I'm writing a script which I want to distribute using Setuptools. I have added this script to the `entry_points` section in my `setup.py`.

From the setuptools docs:

> The functions you specify are called with no arguments, and their return value is passed to sys.exit(), so you can **return an errorlevel or message to print to stderr**.

Since the method will return instead of exit it becomes more testable. For testability purposes I accept arguments in the method defaulting to `sys.argv`. So far so good.

The problem arises when argparse is added to the mix. When argparse fails to parse args it calls `sys.exit`. Now I would really prefer that argparse doesn't do this as this is handled by the setuptools wrapper. The first thing I could think of to fix this is to override the `argparse.ArgumentParser` but then I saw this:

```
# ===============
# Exiting methods
# ===============
def exit(self, status=0, message=None):
    if message:
        self._print_message(message, _sys.stderr)
    _sys.exit(status)

def error(self, message):
    """error(message: string)

    Prints a usage message incorporating the message to stderr and
    exits.

    If you override this in a subclass, it should not return -- it
    should either exit or raise an exception.
    """
    self.print_usage(_sys.stderr)
    self.exit(2, _('%s: error: %s\n') % (self.prog, message))
```

So the docstring states I should not return and stick with raising an exception. How should I solve this?

The main method if I didn't explain it thoroughly enough:

```
def main(args=sys.argv):
    parser = ArgumentParser(prog='spam')

    # parser is configured here

    parsed = parser.parse_args(args)

    # Parsed args are used here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you don't want to `return` from `error` is that the parser will continue parsing.  Some errors are raised near the end (e.g. about unparsed strings), but others can occur early (e.g. bad type for the first argument string). The behavior of `parse_args` is unpredictable if you return from the error method.   Normally you want the parser to quit and return control your code.

What you want to do is wrap the `parse_args()` call in a `try: except SystemExit:` block.  I often use test scripts like this:

```
for test in ['-o FILE',
    ...
         ]:
    print(test)
    try:
        print(parser.parse_args(test.split()))
    except SystemExit:
        pass
```

You could use `error` and/or `exit` to return other kinds of Exceptions. They could also bypass the usage message.   But in one way or other you need to trap the exception in your wrapper.

Comment: Catching `SystemError` will not do any good since `SystemExit` is not a subclass of that. I assume it is a typo. ;-) I have decided to catch the `SystemExit` in my main method, this in turn returns the status code. This doesn't get rid of the troubles I have with testing so I have to keep patching `sys.stdout` and friends to see what is written. Extending `argparse` is a pain since it is vastly undocumented and applies the factory pattern. The point of raising the exception is super obvious and I should not have to ask this. Thanks for your answer. ;-)

Comment: Yes, SysExit is correct.  test_argparse.py  redirects stdout and stderr in its ErrorRaisingArgumentParser class.

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting on a fresh project or have time for some refactoring, then you might consider using the [Click](http://click.pocoo.org/) library. Click has both [setuptools integration](http://click.pocoo.org/5/setuptools/) and '[testability](http://click.pocoo.org/5/testing/)' as features, among other considerations.

Here's an example / test-snippet from the docs that both creates a mini command-line interface, and then tests it immediately:

```
import click
from click.testing import CliRunner

def test_hello_world():
    @click.command()
    @click.argument('name')
    def hello(name):
        click.echo('Hello %s!' % name)

    runner = CliRunner()
    result = runner.invoke(hello, ['Peter'])
    assert result.exit_code == 0
    assert result.output == 'Hello Peter!\n'
```

Comment: Click is quite nice. I personally don't think the documentation is too good, but with a little persistence one finds most of the answers. The rest can be found via stack overflow ;-)